# What does "finalize objects on finalization queue" do?

Tags: java, shortcut, finalize, finalization, java-console

When I open the Java Console in Java SE 7 Update 76, I'm shown a list of keyboard shortcuts I can use for debugging. The shortcut for F is labeled `finalize objects on finalization queue`.

[image: Java Console Help Window]

When I run this shortcut, it prints the following information in the console:

```
Finalize objects on finalization queue ... completed.
Memory: 63,328K  Free: 20,627K  (32%) ... completed.
```

I'm not entirely sure what this command does, or what the information it gives means. The command doesn't seem to have had any noticeable impact on my active Java applications.

**What does the "finalize objects on finalization queue" shortcut do in the Java Console?**

Comment: Do you know what finalization is?

Comment: @chrylis I do not, no

Comment: It's discouraged and rarely used, which is why it doesn't seem to affect your application, but read up on it, and the command should be self-explanatory once you have the concept.